VBA Replace “Start” attribute deletes text
This is a weird one. I am trying to replace the second occurrence of a value using the Replace function. This is what I have.
Sub_string = Replace(sub_string, "<ul>", "", ulnestfound, 1, vbTextCompare)

My thinking is that the Replace function would start looking at position ulnestfound, and replace the first occurrence of "<ul>" from that point. What’s actually happening is that all of the text prior to ulnestfound is being deleted, along with the <ul> tag. So, for example, if ulnestfound = 100, the first 100 characters of sub_string are being deleted,and then the replacement is made.
Any ideas why this is happening? It’s driving me mad.
I’ve tried manually keying the start value, which is how I realized what was happening. I can’t imagine why it would delete text like that.

The documentation of the Replace function says:

Returns a string, which is a substring of a string expression beginning at the start position (defaults to 1), in which a specified substring has been replaced with another substring a specified number of times.

I agree that it doesn't do what most people would assume, but it is consistent with the observed behavior.
You can instead write:
Sub_string = Left(sub_string, ulnestfound - 1) & _
    Replace(sub_string, "<ul>", "", ulnestfound, 1,, vbTextCompare)


Note that the syntax is
Replace(expression, find, replace, [ start, [ count, [ compare ]]])

You omited the count parameter. Either write
Sub_string = Replace(sub_string, "<ul>", "", ulnestfound, 1,, vbTextCompare)

or
Sub_string = Replace(sub_string, "<ul>", "", ulnestfound, 1, Compare:=vbTextCompare)

otherwise vbTextCompare (=1) will be taken as count.

Awesome! Thank you!
